# HttpModule EndRequest handler called twice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I am attempting to implement authentication for a REST service implemented in WCF and hosted on Azure.  I am using HttpModule to handle the AuthenticationRequest, PostAuthenticationRequest and EndRequest events.  If the Authorization header is missing or if the token contained therein is invalid, during EndRequest I am setting the StatusCode on the Response to 401.  However, I have determined that EndRequest is called twice, and on the second call the response has already had headers set, causing the code which sets the StatusCode to throw an exception.

I added locks to Init() to ensure that the handler wasn't being registered twice; still ran twice.  Init() also ran twice, indicating that two instances of the HttpModule were being created.  However, using Set Object ID in the VS debugger seems to indicate that the requests are actually different requests.  I've verified in Fiddler that there is only one request being issued to my service from the browser.

If I switch to using global.asax routing instead of depending on the WCF service host configuration, the handler is only called once and everything works fine.

If I add configuration to the system.web configuration section as well as the system.webServer configuration section in Web.config, the handler is only called once and everything works fine.

So I have mitigations, but I really dislike behavior I don't understand.  Why does the handler get called twice?

Here is a minimal repro of the problem:

Web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="AuthModule" type="TestWCFRole.AuthModule, TestWCFRole"/>
    </httpModules>-->
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="TestWCFRole.Service1">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" name="RestEndpoint" contract="TestWCFRole.IService1" bindingConfiguration="HttpSecurityBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpSecurityBinding" >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="AuthModule" type="TestWCFRole.AuthModule, TestWCFRole"/>
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Http module:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace TestWCFRole
{
    public class AuthModule : IHttpModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this module in the web.config file of your
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>
        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //clean-up code here.
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            // Below is an example of how you can handle LogRequest event and provide 
            // custom logging implementation for it
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);
        }

        #endregion

        public void OnEndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use UrlRewrite in your application? It seems, that it cause EndRequest to fire twice.

Comment: Can it enabled in the background?  I don't have the UrlRewriteModule in my web.config.

Comment: I don't think so. This is really weird, because I can't say that all my problem caused by UrlRewriteModule. But some of them are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry no clue to why it could be called twice, however EndRequest can end up being called for multiple reasons. request finished, request was aborted, some error happened. So i wouldn't put my trust in assuming that if you get there, you actually have a 401, it could be for other reasons.

I'd just keep my logic in the AuthenticateRequest pipeline:

```
    public class AuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose() { }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AuthenticateRequest += Authenticate;
        }

        public static void Authenticate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // authentication logic here            
            //.............

            if (authenticated) {
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(myUser, myRoles);
            }

            // failure logic here           
            //.............         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure why I didn't realize how I should be approaching it before (I suppose I must have thought the sample I was using was doing it "right"), but I eventually moved the logic into the AuthenticateRequest, PostAuthenticateRequest and AuthorizeRequest sections.  Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question as to why the handler behaves this way.

Answer (score 8):

When an ASP.net application starts up,  to maximize performance the ASP.NET Worker process will instantiate as many `HttpApplication` objects as it needs. Each `HttpApplication` object, will also instantiate one copy of each `IHttpModule` that is registered and call the Init method! That's really an internal design of the ASP.NET process running under IIS (or cassini which is VS built in webserver). Might be because your ASPX page has links to other resources which your browser will try to download, an external resource, and iframe, a css file, or maybe ASP.NET Worker Process behavior.

Luckily it's not the case for Global.asax:

[Here's from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29):

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods
>   that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once
>   for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each
>   HttpApplication instance.

However `HTTPModule's init` method is called once for every instance of the HttpApplication class after all modules have been created

> The first time an ASP.NET page or process is requested in an
>   application, a new instance of HttpApplication is created. However, to
>   maximize performance, HttpApplication instances might be reused for
>   multiple requests.

And illustrated by the following diagram:
[image]

If you want code that's guaranteed to run just once, you can either use `Application_Start` of the `Global.asax` or set a flag and lock it in the underlying module which is don't think is a good practice for the sake of Authentication!

Comment: I'd just that the setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` will cause executing the custom module for each and every request, including static files (JS/CSS/Images). So just twice for a single page load seems even too few for me with that setup.

Comment: I don't need code to run a single time; the problem is that I see two EndRequests for a single request to the service.  It shouldn't be JS/CSS/Images, because this is a service, not a web page.  I can see in Fiddler that only a single request is being made.  The question is why I see a single request via Fiddler but two requests in the module, and why this problem goes away if I duplicate the configuration in the web.config.

Comment: Normally you don't need to duplicate the config, if you are using IIS7+ the config must be set in the `system.webServer` section! Does `Init` method of the Module called once while the `EndRequest` is called twice for a single request? because `EndRequest` can not be called twice per request! However I notice that you are enabling `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` in your WCF host configuration, What webserver are you testing with? IIS? IIS Express? VS Web Server? How do you host your WCF in IIS? A `WebServiceHost`? `.svc` file? Can you post the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Path` in the EndRequest?

Comment: Yes, Init module is called once for each HttpApplication. And EndRequest is called twice. In my case UrlRewritingModule is responsible for that.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Path is "/" in both cases.  I believe the hosting is in IIS Express.  The tests were done in VS 2010 and 2012, in the Azure Compute Emulator and also just debugging the WCF service directly.  I created the repro using the Azure template from Azure SDK 1.8; the only changes I made to the project were to add the AuthModule (as above) and the matching changes to the web.config to register the AuthModule.